# Nested jQuery.grep

Tags: jquery, arrays

We can use $.grep to filter out unwanted array items, so

```
data = $.grep(jsonstr, function(d) {
    return d.attr == "x";
})
```

will return only those array objects with attr == x

What if I want to similarly filter arrays that sit under objects, can I do that with $.grep? So

```
    data = $.grep(jsonstr2, function(d) {
        $.grep(d.GL2_ACCTS, function(gl2) {
            return (gl2.localamt > lBound && gl2.localamt < uBound);
        });
        return d.DOC_TYPE == doc;
    });
```

should that filter the arrElement arrays that sit within each element in data?

Data looks as follows:

```
jsonstr =  
[{
  DOC_TYPE: "1A", 
  GL1_ACCOUNT: "Other|Mark Up(Other)", 
  GL2_ACCTS: [
    {name: "Expenses|Conferences(Expenses)", localamt: 123, count: 2},
    {name: "Expenses|Consultancy(Expenses)", localamt: 49, count: 1}
  ]
}]
```

I'm calling this as I change lBound and uBound. It only ever returns everything, no filtering happens.

Comment: _"should that filter arrays of objects in arrElement that sit within elements in jsonStr?"_ Yes . What is purpose of `return d.attr == "x";` Can include example of `jsonstr` at Question ?

Comment: reworded the Q - hopefully clearer now.

Comment: Can include example of `jsonstr` at Question ? Currently inner `$.grep()` does not return any value

Comment: Ahh see what you mean now. You shouldn't need to see the data, the question relates to whether it's possible to filter arrays based on their properties that sit within an array, ie. can I use nested $.grep to filter the underlying arrays as well as the main, data array?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You're not doing anything with the result of the nested `$.grep` call.

Comment: I'm doing as much with the nested call as I'm doing with the outer call - returning only those objects for which the property conforms to the condition. In the outer query this is that the doc_type == the document value, in the inner $.grep the localamt must sit within the bounds.

Comment: You're returning it, but not assigning the return value to anything. In the outer call you assign the result to `data`.

Comment: do I need to assign it as the d.GL2_ACCTS value?

Comment: Yes, that's what you need to do if you want to modify the original object to only contain the accounts that match. `$.grep` doesn't modify the array you give it.

Comment: What is `lBound` , `uBound` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the filtered array back in the object.

```
data = $.grep(jsonstr2, function(d) {
    d.GL2_ACCTS = $.grep(d.GL2_ACCTS, function(gl2) {
        return (gl2.localamt > lBound && gl2.localamt < uBound);
    });
    return d.DOC_TYPE == doc;
});
```

Note that this will filter out the accounts even in objects that weren't returned by the outer `$.grep`. If you don't want to do that, you need to do the `DOC_TYPE` check first:

```
data = $.grep(jsonstr2, function(d) {
    if (d.DOC_TYPE == doc) {
        d.GL2_ACCTS = $.grep(d.GL2_ACCTS, function(gl2) {
            return (gl2.localamt > lBound && gl2.localamt < uBound);
        });
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> You shouldn't need to see the data, the question relates to whether
>   it's possible to filter arrays based on their properties that sit
>   within an array, ie. can I use nested $.grep to filter the underlying
>   arrays as well as the main, data array?

Yes

Comment: Have updated Q  - I initially just wanted to ascertain whether i could do it, now I suspect there's an issue in the code so have added the actual code/example data.